# How to Create a partition key from Azure Portal while creating a collection?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

[image]

There is an option to create a unique key, but I don't see anything related to Partition Key. Can't we create a partition key from Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition keys are for "unlimited" collections (minimum 1000 RU), not fixed collections (which only have one 10GB partition, and are not expandable).

If you choose "Unlimited" for storage capacity, you'll see this option. Currently you have "Fixed (10GB)" chosen.